# How to get a 0 before a datetime day when the day is below 10 in C#

Tags: c#, string, winforms, datetime

I want to have a 0 before the datetime day when the day is below 10

my code:

```
public string p_codigo
{
    get 
    { 
        return $"{data_nascimento.Year}{nome_primeiro.ToUpper().First()}" + 
               $"{nome_ultimo.ToUpper().First()}{data_nascimento.Day.ToString()}"; 
    }
}
```

I have found another answer to question but t wasn't on C#.

Comment: Mix DateTime.ToString with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings.  You can use those formats in an interpolated string ($"This is {interpolated}").

Comment: `str dayString = data_nascimento.Day < 10 ? "0" + data_nascimento.Day.ToString() : data_nascimento.Day.ToString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MS Docs - Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2#ddSpecifier)
using `.ToString("dd")`

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("2018-11-05").ToString("dd")); // => "05"
```

Or as Flydog57 and Xiaoy312 mention with Interpolation
(Thanks - didn't know about the `[:<formatString>]`)

```
Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Parse("2018-11-05"):dd}"); // => "05"
```

[MS Docs - $ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: Atlernatively, use `{data_nascimento:dd}` inside the string interpolation.